# Query that groups based on company, type of withdrawal and the most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that sums based on the withdrawal type and the most recent date (from a table I've listed as c5 in SQL). I also want it to sum the total savings amount from a table c4. I have the following set up:

c5:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| Company | CashAmount | Withdrawal Type | Date       | Interest |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| A       | 10         | Type1           | 02/28/2019 | 5        |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| A       | 20         | Type1           | 02/28/2019 | 1        |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| B       | 15         | Type2           | 01/31/2019 | 1        |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

c4:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| Company | Savings | Date       |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | 5       | 02/28/2019 |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | 5       | 02/28/2019 |
+---------+---------+------------+
| B       | 16      | 01/31/2019 |
+---------+---------+------------+
| B       | 12      | 02/28/2019 |
+---------+---------+------------+
| B       | 1       | 01/31/2019 |
+---------+---------+------------+
| A       | 3       | 12/29/2018 |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

So, based on this sample data I would want to generate the following table:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| Company | Total_Type1 | Total_Type2 | SumOfSavings |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| A       | 30          | 0           | 13           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
| B       | 0           | 0           | 29           |
+---------+-------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I've had a dig at the query using the following SQL, It doesn't work unfortunately.

```
SELECT c4.company, Sum(iif(c5.[withdrawal type] = "type1" AND c5.[date] = max(c5.[date]), [c5].[CashAmount],0)) AS Total_type1, Sum(c4.Savings) as SumofSavings
FROM c004_table1 AS c4 LEFT JOIN c005_table2 AS c5 ON (c4.company = c5.company) AND (c4.[Date] = c5.[Date])
Group by c4.company;
```

Any advice on how to make it work would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is Type2 total for B zero?

Comment: @zedfoxus because I am trying to select entries that have the most recent dates. As company B's cash amount in type2 is corresponding to "01/31/2019" when the most recent date is "02/28/2019" I want it to be ommited. This is different from 'savings amount' which I need to be the sum of all entries regardless of date.

Comment: Are there only 2 withdrawal types?

Comment: @June7 There are many more, but to keep the problem simple I kept it at two. ZedFoxus' idea could be expanded to incorporate more with relative ease in my opinion.

Comment: It can, depending on what 'many more' means - 20 or 200?

Comment: Many more is perhaps a bit ambiguous and overstated - It's 11 to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    c5.company,
    sum(
        iif(
            c5.[withdrawal type] = "type1" and c5.[withdrawal date] >= cd.savingsdate,
            c5.cashamount,
            0
        )
    ) as type_1,
    sum(
        iif(
            c5.[withdrawal type] = "type2" and c5.[withdrawal date] >= cd.savingsdate,
            c5.cashamount,
            0
        )
    ) as type_2,
    min(cd.sumsavings) as s
from c5
inner join 
(
    select company, max([savings date]) as savingsdate, sum(savings) as sumsavings
    from c4
    group by company
) cd on c5.company = cd.company
group by c5.company
```

Instead of the reserved word `Date`, I have used [savings date] to reduce my own confusion.

**Screenshot of c4 table**

[image]

**Screenshot of c5 table**

[image]

**Result of query**

[image]

Comment: Does not return total for company A type 1.

Comment: Are you sure? I have the same tables as you do and I get the right information.

Comment: Amazing! This works perfectly for me and I am able to expand this idea to help with the larger issue at hand. Thanks!

Comment: I am not SadMrFrown, I am trying to replicate tables and queries. I can't see where I am going wrong. But looks like OP got it to work.

Comment: @June7 create a new question with your problem set and call me out in a comment to this answer with the link. That way, we keep SadMrFrown's question and answers intact and work on your problem separately.

Comment: I don't have an issue and don't need an answer, was just trying to work through this question to develop an answer when other answers were provided first I tried to work with those. No matter now.

Comment: Ah, gotcha @June7! You have created c4 and c5 tables, is that correct? Are you familiar with creating a Query in Design Mode and switching to SQL?

Comment: Definitely. Found it. Copy/pasted data from Excel and ended up with leading spaces in the WithdrawalText data! I messed up parsing. Works now. I was thinking of a CROSSTAB joined to the inner Aggregate but this works. I wonder if there are only the 2 WithdrawalTypes.

Comment: Outstanding. Great job @June7.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate the second table first, to get the maximum date.  Then aggregate again to bring in the information from the first table.

```
select t1.company,
       sum(iif(Withdrawal_type = "type_1", cashamount, 0)) as type_1,
       sum(iif(Withdrawal_type = "type_2" and t1.date = t2.max_date, cashamount, 0)) as type_2,
       t2.sum_savings
from c004_table1 as t1 left join
     (select company, sum(savings) as sum_savings, max(date) as max_date
      from c005_table2
      group by company
     ) as t2
     on t2.company = t1.company
group by t1.company, t2.sum_savings;
```

Comment: Table references don't agree with the posted info but on the right track.